# How long the jmeter script will run for single user if video duration is 10mins

Tags: video, https, jmeter, http-live-streaming

If we have .mp4 video hosted on website which has 10mins duration and when script is created in jmeter to play that video for single user, will the test run for 10mins for single user?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which will simply download the video the duration of the request will be limited by server response time and your internet connection bandwidth.

So if you want to mimic user watching the video you need to introduce a [think time](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time) equal to your video duration which can be done using a [JMeter Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers/)

Also if browser requests the video by chunks you might want to replicate this behavior as well by requesting first part, second part, etc. of the video using [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and [Range header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range)